# twilio will not hangup after hangup is issued via twiml

Tags: twilio

hello all I am making an attempt to interface with a remote IVR with the following Twiml. MY issue is that twilio doesn't hangup until 130+ minutes later, however it does only record the 10 seconds as asked. Any insight would be greatly appreciated

```
<Response>
    <Play digits="1w1w1234567w8w1w9w1w21ww1"> </Play>
    <Record timeout="10" transcribe="false" maxLength="10"/>
    <Pause length="10"/>
    <Hangup/>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an action URL to the `<Record>` verb to prevent unwanted looping.

[Record Action Attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record#attributes-action)